# Ajuda - Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #[object HTMLFormElement]

Tags: jquery, ajax, formulário, post

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][image: erro no console]

Problema no validar um formulario com ajax, segue o erro..

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "adicionaConcorrente",
    cache: false,
    data: $("#" + varForm).serialize(),
    beforeSend: function() {
        // Faz alguma coisa antes de enviar
    },
    success: function(result) {
        $("#" + id).html("");
        $("#" + id).html(result);
        $('#idDoModal').modal('show');
    },
    complete: function() {
        // Faz alguma coisa depois que terminar
    }
});
```

Comment: Tens de colocar o código que estás a usar para podermos ajudar mais. Por exemplo como é essa função adicionaConcorrente?

Comment: O url estará bem? É só `adicionaconcorrente`?

Comment: sim adicionaConcorrente?+parâmetros

Comment: Não faltam os parametros? e não será qql coisa como `http://www.meusite.com/adicionaconcorrente.php?param1=123&param2=123`?

Comment: ele pegaria na função, onde: data: $("#" + varForm).serialize(),

Comment: Jovem, provavelmente o erro pode estar no la linha `data: $("#" + varForm).serialize()`, qual o valor desse `varForm` ? joga no console o valor e verifica nomavente

Comment: correto, o erro esta no  $("#" + varForm).serialize():

correção: ("#varForm").serialize():